# jQuery AJAX http GET cross domain - required headers in response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I've made a web application running on domain http://app.mydomain.tld
and I've APIs on https://api.mydomain.tld (APIs are not developed by me).

I'm doing an AJAX HTTPs GET call with jQuery using this method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.mydomain.tld/GetSomething/read.php",
    method: "GET",
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    async:false,
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) { doSomething(); },
    error: function (data) { showError(); }
});
```

This call is returning an error like `NetworkError: failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://api.mydomain.tld/GetSomething/read.php'`.

I've added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension for Chrome and the call is working fine.

So I've checked response headers. When Chrome extension is NOT enabled I've this response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

When the extension is enabled I've these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

So my question, that could have an obvious answer, is: are these headers required to make correct cross domain calls?
If yes, do my APIs need the below additional code?

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin");
?>
```

Is correct what I said or am I missing something to make my call working without changing APIs code?

PS: if possibile I would not use JSONP.

Comment: You should not allow this much, when it is way more than what is actually needed. Your GET request does not need all the other HTTP methods to be allowed as well, for example. Is the error message you quoted all you get? That would be a bit surprising, normally you should get an error message specifically referring to CORS, and explaining what exactly was missing or wrong.

Comment: @misorude thanks! Obviously I will add only GET method. That's the error message returned in .error() of my $.ajax(). On browser console I receive "blocked cross-origin request" errors (Firefox) or other errors mentioning CORS (Google Chrome).

Comment: Ah yes, I was referring to the error messages in the browser console. Go check these again, in Chrome - they are usually pretty detailed regarding what exactly the issue is, and should be able to help figure out what exactly needs to be added. (Fixing one error might lead to the next one then, but if you don’t want to be “overly generous” in what you allow, I think going this way is preferable.)